# How to get only the function names in an inherited class in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to get only the function names in an inherited class in python

```
class A(object):
    def Afunc1(self):
        pass

    def Afunc2(self):
        pass

class B(A):
    def Bfunc1(self):
        pass

    def Bfunc2(self):
        pass
```

Is there any way to get only function names in B class not in A class

Answer (score 6):

This should work:

```
from types import FunctionType
functypes = (FunctionType, classmethod, staticmethod)
[name for name, value in B.__dict__.items() if isinstance(value, functypes)]
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `vars` function to get the attribute dict of the class `B` itself and filter out the non-callables and classes:

```
[k for k, v in vars(B).items() if callable(v) and not isinstance(v, type)]
```

Comment: beware, `callable()` returns true for classes, so if the class has another class as class attribute (and this is not uncommon), you will get false positives. That's why I explicitely tested against functions, classmethods and staticmethods.

Comment: @bruno Adding `and not isinstance(v, type)` works around that, right?

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Indeed. +1

Comment: @wjandrea for classes, yes, but not for other custom callable objects...

Comment: @bruno Right, like callable class instances.